# Odd PreferenceActivity Theme on Samsung Devices

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-theme, samsung-mobile

I'm seeing a very odd theme issue in my `PreferenceActivity` only on Samsung devices (as far as I'm aware).

-----EDIT (Removed irrelevant code)-----------

The following is an unthemed preference activity:

```
<activity android:name=".FullSettingsActivity"/>
```

[image]

Setting  theme for the FullSettingsActivity:

```
<activity android:name=".FullSettingsActivity"
          android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
```

yields this:

[image]

So clearly the default theme for Samsung devices is rather odd.  Is there any reason a PreferenceActivity would end up unreadable like that only on Samsung devices?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the relevance of the link.  A toolbar is not needed.  I just don't know why Samsung devices have that awful color theme where you can't see text.

Comment: Question updated with a screenshot of what happens when I explicitly set the `PreferenceActivity` theme.

Comment: Probably, you need to ask Samsung...For now, you can either put `android:theme` in XML or call `Activity.setTheme()` from code to enforce theme styling.

Comment: Yah, it's an odd one that's for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your theme from `@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` to something else like `android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar` and see the difference.

Also make sure you add that GalleryTheme in your AppManifest.xml in your application tag like `android:theme="@style/GalleryTheme"`

Hope that helps.

Comment: If he is using `AppCompat v7` support library, he can't use any style not from `Theme.AppCompat` parent

Comment: As @eee mentioned, anything but AppCompat will crash immediately.  I can't even test another theme on a 5.0 device, due to the heavy dependence on AppCompat.

Comment: However I did try:
`@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`
and it changed the main activity, but the settings remain unaffected.

Comment: Question updated with a screenshot of what happens when I explicitly set the `PreferenceActivity` theme.